# Docker pull repositoryName don't work can't see public repos

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

So im trying to pull a fresh repository from docker, wich it seems to be pretty easy but i just can't.

Im seeing this (check image)

[image]

but im getting "repository not found", this is what im running.

```
bash-3.2$ docker pull ethaan/test
Pulling repository ethaan/test
Repository not found
bash-3.2$
```

Also im trying with Kitematic, but its kinda the same, here are som ss from kitmatic.

First the "my repos view"

[image]

Now when i click on "create", i got this error.

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]
[image]

**Updating Start Repository email image**

[image]

**Update view from docker hub enterprise**
[image]

Comment: Also, its not the `Update view from docker hub enterprise ` but `View from Docker Hub Beta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to pull it because you just don't have any tags in `ethaan/test`. That is, the repository is empty. Once you push a tag, you will be able to pull it. 
Just to test, try the following:
`docker pull busybox`
`docker tag busybox ethaan/test:test`
`docker push ethaan/test:test`
Then you will be able to pull it as:
`docker pull ethaan/test:test`

Comment: This is the same thing said here ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252664/docker-pull-repositoryname-dont-work-cant-see-public-repos/31253822#comment50505077_31253822

Comment: I wish I could answer your answer! I up-voted it though ;)

Answer (score 3):

If this is a private repository (it doesn't exist from my view), you will need to login first.

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/login/

> Usage: docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]
>
> Register or log in to a Docker registry server, if no server is
>   specified "https://index.docker.io/v1/" is the default.
>
> -e, --email=""       Email
>
> -p, --password=""    Password
>
> -u, --username=""    Username

Comment: i create it as a public, i need to say that i have a free account dont really know if that matters (it say that you get 1 private repo), but the thing here is that i made the repository public but like you i cant see the repo anyware, i need to publish it somewhere to make it avaible? or just by "creating a new repository" the thing will appear avaible to everyone?

Comment: just update 2 more images, so i don't really know why my repos are not avails

Comment: I see it now. It's there, but it's completely empty... so it's a home for a repository but you need to put a Dockerfile there for it to build.

Comment: also updating an image with an email i get from my repo starred

Comment: I can see your user and repositories but there's nothing inside them.